# Weird bug happening with Django and MySQL

Tags: mysql, django, django-orm

I have two pieces of code, both doing the same thing but one takes 50 seconds and other takes less than 5 seconds.

**Models**

```
class Device(models.Model):
    device_uid = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, null=False)


class DeviceReadings(models.Model):
    device = models.ForeignKey(Device)
    value = models.FloatField(default=0)
    created_dt = models.DateTimeField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('created_dt', 'device')
```

The DeviceReadings table contains around 200 million rows.

If i do this, mysql query won't use index and will scan 22 million rows and takes 40 seconds.

```
#'D1,D2,D3' are comma separated device_uid's
my_devices = "D1,D2,D3".split(",")
devices = Device.objects.filter(device_uid__in=my_devices)
readings = DeviceReadings.objects.filter(created_dt__gte=start_time, created_dt__lte=end_time, device__in=devices)
```

However, if i do this, mysql query will use index and will only scan 1 million rows and takes around 4 seconds.

```
my_devices = "D1,D2,D3".split(",")
my_devices_ob = Device.objects.filter(device_uid__in=my_devices)
devices = []
for device in my_devices_ob:
    devices.append(device)
readings = DeviceReadings.objects.filter(created_dt__gte=start_time, created_dt__lte=end_time, device__in=devices)
```

If i print the devices array, it is same in both the codes. Can someone explain what might be happening here ?

Answer (score 0):

Remember that querysets are lazy. In your first code, the `Device.objects.filter` is not executed at the time you define it. Since you use it immediately inside another query, Django translates that into a subquery in the form:

```
SELECT * FROM device_readings WHERE device_id IN (SELECT id FROM devices WHERE ...);
```

whereas in the second query, you explicitly execute the second query, so Django does:

```
SELECT * FROM device_readings WHERE device_id IN ("device_id_1", "device_id_2"...);
```

Normally, the first query is actually more performant, since you don't need to fetch the device data separately. You should investigate why that isn't the case with EXPLAIN.

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply, I forgot about the lazy nature of querysets. I looked at the generated raw query and in slower code it has following where clause 
"(`devicereadings`.`device_id`) IN (SELECT U0.`id` FROM `core_device` U0 WHERE U0.`device_uid` IN (D1, D2, D3))"

and in faster one
"(`devicereadings`.`device_id`) IN (1, 2, 3)"

Is subquery the reason why mysql is not using index in first one ?

Answer (score 0):

Both queries should have virtually identical performance, with a penalty for the second query that is negligible for large tables. So your results are quite unusual; can you consistently replicate them?

I'm wondering if the subquery makes MySQL change the order in which the conditions are evaluated, filtering on the dates first in the second query. That would appear to be the case if adding an index to `created_dt` speeds up the second query:

```
created_dt = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
```

I'm also curious how the following would compare:

```
my_devices = "D1,D2,D3".split(",")
readings = DeviceReadings.objects.filter(
    created_dt__gte=start_time, 
    created_dt__lte=end_time,
    device__uid__in=my_devices)
```

It gives you slightly cleaner code, but it might not be quicker.